# How to make scaled units in Boost Units convertable to string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I want to define the unit Watt hours which has the same dimensions as Joule but needs a conversion factor of 3600. Therefore, I want to define it as a scaled unit.

I've defined my unit as follows:

```
namespace si = boost::units::si;
typedef boost::units::make_scaled_unit<si::energy, boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1>>>::type watt_hour_unit;
BOOST_UNITS_STATIC_CONSTANT(watt_hours, watt_hour_unit);
typedef boost::units::quantity<watt_hour_unit> watt_hour;
```

I can use it without problems:

```
watt_hour const energy_whs = 1.0 * watt_hours;
boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::energy, double> energy_conv(energy_whs);
std::cout << energy_conv << std::endl; // "3600 J"
```

But when I try to print it, I get an error:

```
std::cout << energy_whs << std::endl; // should be "1 Wh"
```

yields these errors

```
[...]
/usr/include/boost/units/io.hpp:327:39: error: ‘symbol’ is not a member of ‘boost::units::list<boost::units::scale_list_dim<boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1> > >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>::item’ {aka ‘boost::units::scale_list_dim<boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1> > >’}
  327 |             str += Begin::item::symbol();
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
[...]
/usr/include/boost/units/io.hpp:393:37: error: ‘name’ is not a member of ‘boost::units::list<boost::units::scale_list_dim<boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1> > >, boost::units::dimensionless_type>::item’ {aka ‘boost::units::scale_list_dim<boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1> > >’}
  393 |             str += Begin::item::name();
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I tried defining the `name_string` and `symbol_string` which makes the second error disappear but not the first.

```
namespace boost
{
namespace units
{
std::string name_string(const watt_hour_unit&)
{
    return "Watt hours";
}

std::string symbol_string(const watt_hour_unit&)
{
    return "Wh";
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why people downvote this. I love this type of question because it gives exactly where the library use breaks down for new users. I actually looked at this for some 45 minutes and couldn't figure it out. I hope someone else spots the problem (my intuition says that `energy` is supposed to be a unit, not a dimension, but (a) it compiles (b) I couldn't figure out how to fix it; Another thing is that I think the `name_string`/`symbol_string` overloads might need to be in `::boost::units` due to ADL)

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I missed the namespace, I had them in my code but forgot to add them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaled units only can be printed when the scale is a certain power of 10 or a certain power of 2. This is because boost::units::scale is specialized for those particular scales.

You need to specialize `boost::units::scale<3600, boost::units::static_rational<1>>>`.

```
namespace bu = boost::units;
template <>
struct bu::scale<3600, bu::static_rational<1>>
{
      BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR long base = 3600;
      typedef bu::static_rational<1> exponent;
      typedef double value_type;
      static BOOST_CONSTEXPR value_type value()   { return(3600); }
      static std::string name()   { return("x3600"); }
      static std::string symbol() { return("x3600"); }
};
```

"x3600" is an arbitrary string I chose to represent a factor of 3600. It will be used for output of watt-hour quantities only if you do **not** define  `name_string` and `symbol_string` as you did. So you need both these functions and this specialization.

Comment: Would it not be better to use `scale<60, boost::units::static_rational<2> >` anyways? Or that might actually already be implemented?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978cc232a831384a proof of concept

Comment: @sehe you can do that too of course if you feel that base 60 should be used more.